# Script creation of iOS Push Notification Certificates

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

Is there any such thing, or is the only option to do the clicking about in the Apple Developer site like I have been?  To be clear, I mean a programmatic or API-sort of method for generating certificates without manually doing it for each app on the website.  The use case, naturally, is doing this for a lot of apps as a batch instead of doing each app one at a time.  I know how to work with the certs once I have them. I suspect the answer is no, but just because I don't know of one, doesn't make the question a bad one!  Thanks!

Comment: Basically it's possible, but the step to upload the CSR and download the certificate cannot be automated. The other steps, creating a CSR from the private key, add the certificate to the keychain, convert to other formats, include the password, upload to server etc. can be accomplished with `Security.framework` and the third party `MCrypto.framework`. I wrote an Assistant to recreate Push Certificates which works very well, just the upload-download step must be done manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Felix Krause ruby gems. They work like a charm, and you can also use the rest of his tools to automate provisioning profiles, screenshots and itunes connect metadate and binary upload.

https://github.com/fastlane/PEM

Comment: That'd do it pretty much exactly.